# Can you make the Wither on the console?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is the Wither in Minecraft on the Xbox 360? Can you spawn it?

Comment: So you are asking if the wiki page http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Wither is up-to-date or?

Comment: @deutschZuid before the edit the question was asking if you could make a Wither or not on the console and if no when will it be and how, the second part of the question can't be answered and the final part would be assumed from the link you posted

Comment: This is likely comeing in TU19

Answer (score 1):

**No**. The Wither and Wither Skeletons are not in Minecraft for console at this time. They only exist in the PC version.